# Wordpress не удается подключить стили

Tags: css, wordpress

Все перепроверил несколько раз. Не знаю где ошибка. Буду признателен за помощь

```
function crea_load_styles()
{
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('fa-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,500,700|Ubuntu:300,400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic');
  wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'crea_load_styles', 10);

?>
```

Comment: Во второй строчке надо /css... И тема у вас какая - основная или дочерняя?

Comment: создаю свою тему в первый раз

Comment: вроде основная тема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вордпрессе есть такой файл style.css, он лежит в корне шаблона, если вы его не создали, ничего работать не будет.

Также в head вашей темы нужно добавить функцию wp_head(); - чтобы вордперсс понял куда стили добавлять.

Comment: head тег должен быть в файле header.php
файл style.css может быть пустым.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
  <header id="header">

Comment: мой header.php , style.css есть

Comment: встроенные стили добавляются, а мои -нет

Comment: Чтобы не гадать, просто зайди в тему twentyseventeen или любую другую и посмотри как там сделано. =)

Comment: спасибо за совет